# RDF4J method for splitting literal into value and datatype

Tags: scala, sparql, sesame, rdf4j

If I have connection `cxn` to an empty triplestore and I say:

```
val CheckSparql = "select (count(?s) as ?scount) where { ?s ?p ?o . }"

val PreparedSparql = cxn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, CheckSparql)
val Result = PreparedSparql.evaluate()
val ResBindSet = Result.next()
val TripleCount = ResBindSet.getValue("scount")

println(TripleCount.toString())
```

I get

```
"0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>
```

***Is there an RDF4J method for retrieving just the value of that literal?***

***I just want 0 or "0", without the datatype***

I figured I should try to do this without string manipulation/regular expressions if possible.

Comment: `getValue` returns an instance of type [`Value`](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/2.2/org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/Value.html). I guess you have to check for the type and cast it to the appropriate type. In your case, it should be a [Literal](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/2.2/org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/Literal.html) which provides a method called `integerValue()` to get the integer value. Untested: `TripleCount.asInstanceOf[Literal].integerValue()`

Comment: @AKSW yeah, that works.  thanks.  this also seems to work:  `val tripleCountInt = tripleCount.stringValue().toInt`  can you think of any reason not to do that?

Comment: I guess for a COUNT query this should always work, so I think your solution would be safe. Otherwise, the answer of @JeenBroekstra shows another solution. Feel free to choose your favorite solution, all of them work as expected :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Literals util class](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/util/Literals.html) is your friend:

```
int scount = Literals.getIntValue(ResBindSet.getValue("scount"))
```

or if you prefer a string:

```
String scount =  Literals.getLabel(ResBindSet.getValue("scount"))
```

You can also optionally add a fallback argument, for example if the supplied argument turns out not to be a literal.